# Shared preferences is working on Lollipop and marshmallow but not in kitkat

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

When i kill the app shared preferences key value is removing, I added token value in shared preferences, when i run in Lolipop, its fine but not working in kitkat, I tried a lot but not got satisfying result.

SplashActivity.java

```
public class SplashActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);

    String authToken = new DevicePreferences().getString(SplashActivity.this, Global_Variables.AUTH_TOKEN, "");

    if (new DevicePreferences().getString(SplashActivity.this, Global_Variables.AUTH_TOKEN, "").equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Intent i = new Intent(SplashActivity.this, WelcomeActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
                finish();
            }
        }, 3000);
    } else {
        Intent intent = new Intent(SplashActivity.this, HomeActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }
}
}
```

DevicePreferences.java

```
public class DevicePreferences {

public SharedPreferences get(Context context) {
    return context.getSharedPreferences(Global_Variables.PREF_FILE_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
}

public void addKey(Context context, String key, String value) {
    SharedPreferences settings = get(context);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
    editor.putString(key, value);
    editor.commit();
}

public String getString(Context context, String key, String defValue) {
    SharedPreferences prefs = get(context);
    return prefs.getString(key, defValue);
}
}
```

Global_Variables.java

```
public class Global_Variables  {
public static final String PREF_FILE_NAME = "GFresh";
public static String AUTH_TOKEN = "auth_token";
}
```

Comment: Can you please post code where you have write into Shared preferences?

Comment: yes i sent login screen

Comment: DevicePreferences devicePreferences = new DevicePreferences();
 -                devicePreferences.addKey(LoginActivity.this, Global_Variables.isSignedUser, false);